# Access to parent router params in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 14, have a route config:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: ':page',
    component: PageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        canActivate: [ValidPathGuard],
        path: ':subPage',
        component: SubPageComponent
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

ValidPathGuard:

```
export class ValidPathGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    console.log(route);
  }
}
```

route.params output only: {subPath: 'subPath'}

if I want access to `:page` need to use route.parent.params: {path: 'path'}

But what if I will use three level of route.

The question is any way how I can get objet with all params?
like: {
path: 'path',
subPath: 'subPath'
}

Answer (score 0):

try access the parent  instance of the route and keep searching for the parent until you have no parent (using recursive)

```
function mergeRouteParams(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, getter: (r: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => Params): Params {
    if (!route) {
        return {};
    }
    const currentParams = route.params;
    return { ...mergeRouteParams(route.parent), ...currentParams };
}
```